# Prestashop add to cart button error

Tags: prestashop, cart, submit-button

i have this problem with button "add to cart" and i don't know whats wrong. It just happened. No code have been edited. When button is pressed it is disabled for sort time. Any ideas where code could have gone wrong? Is this CSS problem or something else?

[image]

Comment: Hi, in order for us to help, you need to reproduce a scenario when this happens.

Comment: @gskema this is button when you want to add to cart. It happens all time when you want add any product to a cart. Something went wrong with button.

Comment: You need to check your JavaScript console when you press the button, it may cache / browser related, because it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a product to cart the button is disabled.
You'll find all the code in:

```
/yourtemplate/js/modules/blockcart/ajax-cart.js
```

If ajax-cart.js isn't edited, at row 304 you'll find this:

```
$(callerElement).prop('disabled', 'disabled');
```

After the ajax call you have:

```
if (addedFromProductPage)
    $('#add_to_cart button').removeProp('disabled').removeClass('disabled');
else
    $(callerElement).removeProp('disabled');
```

So to answer at your question, it's not a problem, you have to adjust your css for disabled button, and you'll get the way :)